# Insert data in table behlf of prticuler id

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to insert data into the database by Id. I
have three questions and I have the answers of these questions. Question
id is inserted correctly in the table. But the answer Id of these questions
is not inserted correctly. Only one question answer is inserted in
the table. Let me explain the function:

`$post['SurveyAnswer']['question_id']` has three values. If we `print_r( $post['SurveyAnswer']['question_id'])` then result is.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 833
    [1] => 834
    [2] => 835
)
```

Now I have the answer of this question. And output of `print_r($post['SurveyAnswer']['answer']);`
    is.

```
Array
(
    [0] => text123
    [1] => hello
    [2] => hello
)
```

What I am trying to do, is save answers in the database with a particular question. 
I need result like this.

```
   [833] => text123
   [834] => hello
   [835] => hello
```

Here is my function

```
public function actionSaveAnswer()
{
    $post = \Yii::$app->request->post();
    // echo "<pre>";print_r($post);die();
    foreach ($post['SurveyAnswer']['question_id'] as $ques) {
        $post['SurveyAnswer']['answer'];
        $surveyAnswer = new SurveyAnswer();
        $surveyAnswer->question_id = $ques;

    }
    if ($surveyAnswer->save()) {
        $flag = true;
        \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', \Yii::t('app', 'Your answers saved successfully.'));
    }
}
```

Comment: the `$surveyAnswer->save()` call is outside `foreach` and you should use transactions when working with related records like in the above scenario, where you can roll back the transaction in case an error is thrown while inserting answers so that irrelevant insertion of questions with out any answer should be avoided

Comment: Muhammad Omer Aslam @please can you post your answere@ this will be big help for me

Comment: it does not look like you are saving the questions along with the answers , your questions are already saved what i assume so you dont need to use transactions, and moving the `save()` call inside the for loop should solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you add the answers. If your answer and question ids match as you indicated then try something like this:

```
foreach ($post['SurveyAnswer']['question_id'] as $id => $ques) {
    $surveyAnswer = new SurveyAnswer();
    $surveyAnswer->question_id = $ques;
    $surveyAnswer->answer = $post['SurveyAnswer']['answer'][$id];
    $surveyAnswer->save();
}
```

And you should save an answer in the cycle. Otherwise only one row will be saved.

Comment: Efim Tarasenko@I am getting errroUndefined offset: 0, in this line,, $surveyAnswer->answer = $post['SurveyAnswer']['answer'][$id];

Comment: Efim Tarasenko@you there?

Comment: What do you have in array `$post['SurveyAnswer']['answer']`?

Comment: Efim Tarasenko @Array
(
    [0] => text123
    [1] => hello
    [2] => hello
)

Comment: If you have `$post['SurveyAnswer']['question_id']` with the same ids 0, 1, 2, then the error *errroUndefined offset* should not occur.

Comment: Just show all your `$post['SurveyAnswer']` dump. Unfortunately I can't enter to teamviewer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207461/discussion-between-efim-tarasenko-and-sanjay-yadav).

Comment: Efim Tarasenko@array(4) {
  ["research_id"]=>
  string(3) "550"
  ["question_id"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "833"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "834"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "835"
  }
  ["answer"]=>
  array(2) {
    [833]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(20) "hello this i s sanay"
    }
    [835]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "helllo"
    }
  }
  ["image"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}

Comment: Efim Tarasenko@you there?